# Boolean Randomness - Recursion... or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

Trying to create a random (0/1) `boolean` operation. I have a multidimensional array set up. So far, everything works. Am I on the right path? I currently use recursion; is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
function randomMove(){
    var cs=b.length,
    cr=Math.floor((Math.random()*cs)+1)-1,
    cc=Math.floor((Math.random()*cs)+1)-1;
    if(b[cr][cc]===""){ // THIS IS DEPENDENT ON EXISTING CODE. VIEW FIDDLE. //
        // DO STUFF //
    } else { randomMove(); }
}
```

Is this considered a good way to create a random move for 2 players? Or is recursion the wrong process here?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ehqka/)

Comment: Select the cells that are empty, then select a random one by index. that would likely be much more efficient than using recursion, since recursion could possibly test the same spot multiple times.

Comment: I've considered that, so make a temp array of "valid" numbers, and run the test on that, then return as the index?

Comment: Nope, it's simpler than that. :)

Comment: Well, i guess my answer does technically still do that, just not in as many steps.

Comment: But... at the same time, if your recursive method finds a good spot on it's first iteration, it's faster than my method. All depends on how many times it has to loop to find a valid move, which of course will grow with the size of the table and the number of open moves remaining. My method will also take longer with more cells, but it wont take any longer on the last move than it does the first.

Comment: We're looking at up to 100

Comment: so 10k possible moves, meaning on move 1, thereis a 1 in 10k chance it will not find an open move on each iteration. On the last move, there is a 1 in 10thousand chance that it WILL find a move, meaning it could iterate 10thousand times or pssibly even more before it finds an open spot. Or it could find it on the first iteration if you're lucky.

Comment: Interesting points... well, I'm going to start throwing some logic at it instead of randomness and we'll see from there :-) Just needed it for the first comp move IF they went first.

Comment: Well... in that case, your method is likely going to be the better one since if all of the moves are possible moves, it should end on the first iteration no matter which one it chooses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the cells that can possibly be selected, then choose a random one by index.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ehqka/1/

```
$.fn.random = function(){
    return this.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length));
};
function randomMove(){
    $("#board td").not(".o,.comp").random().addClass('comp');
    testWin();
}
```

It selects all cells in the board, drops the ones that have a class of `o` or `comp` from the selection, generates a random number between 0 and the number of remaining cells, then selects the cell at that index to add a class to.

Note, however, your method will be "faster" than the above on the first move due to the fact that on the first move, every move is a valid one therefore it will never iterate past the first time. Mine can be slightly optimized to be more efficient on the first by removing the `.not()`, but your's should still be "faster" because it doesn't have to go to the DOM.

"faster" is relative, my method will grow less efficient as the table grows than yours will on the first move. As more and more moves happen, your method will become less and less efficient since more and more of the possible moves are invalid.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I understand that quite well. Took me a second, but `(".o,.comp")` is referring to `array value` vs `class value`. That's pretty nice :-)

Comment: That's just a css selector to filter out. for example, `a:hover, a:visited {...` uses the same concept to select both hovered and visited anchor tags.

Comment: It could likely be improved by filtering your array rather than dom nodes, though i'm having trouble wrapping my head around selecting a random array element from an array of arrays.

Comment: Well, the whole goal of how I've been TRYING to make it, is that everything is cached in array `b` and `DOM` manipulation only happens when necessary... I think it's looking good so far (for the most part).

Comment: I have to test diagonals :-P Its a super expanded tic tac toe program I'm trying to make to challenge myself.

Comment: I personally wouldn't have it just pick a random move, that makes the game super easy :p It would be easy to make it really hard, but to get somewhere in the middle between super hard and possible will take a bit of thought.

Comment: No, you're right. I was testing my DOM manipulation and making everything clean and organized before I wrote an `AI` - Which happens to be my specialty :-) Just learning some new syntax, that's all.

Comment: ty! I appreciate your insight.